# Nonlinear constraint - Convexity

Tags: logarithms, convex-optimization

I have a nonlinear constraint of the form:
z * exp(-x) >= d
where z and x are non-negative bounded variables and the lower bound of z is 0; d is a fixed positive number.

I used the logarithmic transformation to get:

ln(z)- x >= ln(d)

which would be convex if z >0. However, z can take value 0.
Is there a trick to avoid this issue, taking the logarithm of a variable that can be equal to 0?

Under which condition is the function z * exp(x) concave?

Comment: $d$ must be positive, so it is greater than zero and not equal to zero.  $exp(-x)$ cannot be zero for finite positive $x$ so $z$ must be positive (i.e. non-zero).  So there is no issue with taking the log of zero.

Comment: Treat $z = 0$ separately. When $z = 0$, the original inequality turns into $0 \ge d$. But, if $d > 0$, this is never satisfied, for any $x$. So, there are no feasible points $(x, z)$ with $z = 0$.

Comment: The constraint $z e^{-x} \geq d$ is equivalent to $de^x \leq z$, which is a convex constraint for all $(z,x) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ iff $d\geq 0$.